# Unif convergence of sequences of infinitely diff complex functions does not imply uniform convergence of derivative on compact sets.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, holomorphic-functions

This problem is from Greene and Krantz-Function Theory of One Complex Variable Chapter 3. I could not find any couterexample. Could anyone help? Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's a good practice to transcribe your screenshot and put it in a block quote.

Comment: Counter-example to what ? The convolution by $\varphi_n(x,y) = n^2 e^{-\pi n^2(x^2+y^2)}$ provide a way to approximate uniformly a function $f$ bounded and uniformly continuous on $U \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ by a sequence of real-analytic functions $f_n = f \ast \varphi_n$. Clearly the limit doesn't have to be differentiable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n} \sin(nx)$. Then $(f_n)$ converges uniformly on $ \mathbb R$ to $f=0$.

We have $f_n'(x)= \cos(nx)$. Hence $(f_n')$ does not converge uniformly on compact subsets of $ \mathbb R$.